# iOS Safari - automated browser session

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, tools, browser-session

I'm looking for a automation for the following. 
I have a list (just plan text) of around 10000 URLs which belongs to a simulated surf session. Now I want to replay this surf session on different iOS devices in an automated way. 
Is there any tool, which you would recommend where I can load/ configure this list and this tool will than open a Safari on an iOS device and will than load one URL after another (either with a configured waiting/sleeping time between 2 URLs or with the real time difference from the simulated surf session).

I know there are record/replay tools out there, but I'm looking first for any approach/tool where I haven't to go through all the URLs manually first.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/19184035/631619 ?